# To decide how much gain a person has achieved

Tags: soft-question

I am bit confused about following question asked in previous year exam which is as follows :

Rakesh purchased a horse for Rs. 3000 and sold it the same day for Rs. 3600, allowing the buyer a credit of 2 years. If the prevailing rate of interest be 10% per annum, then Rakesh has a net gain of:

A.  0%

B.  5%

C.  7.5%

D.  10%

The answer given is 0% and I don't understand how. I am also confused about the terminology used like 'credit of 2 years' and 'prevailing rate of interest'.

Any help will be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: I agree it is phrased poorly.  The way I'd read it:  "the sale price is $3600$ but payment will not be made for $2$ years.  Thus Rakesh has extended a $2$ year loan for $3600$.  Assuming that the interest on that loan is $10\%$ annual, what is the present value of that $3600$?"

Comment: present value will be 3000 i agree, but he sold it for 3600, so he had some profit.. then why answer is 0%?

Comment: If you trade an asset with a present value of $3000$ for another asset with a present value of $3000$ your gain is $0$.